# How do I solve the error "The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139" in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: updates

I ran the update command in the Terminal:

```
Sudo apt update
```

Updating ends with the following error:

```
The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
Hit:13 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease       
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/morphis/anbox-support/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease [15.4 kB]
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 883E8688397576B6C509DF495A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'Sources' as repository 'https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ingalex/super-boot-manager/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 883E8688397576B6C509DF495A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried going to software and updates then tried to change the source repositories, but nothing sims to work. And help would be gladly appreciated

Comment: It's Software & Updates > Other software where you can find and remove the non-working PPAs

Comment: Any of those PPA lines that have trusty in them are long since dead.  You will need to find the focal equivalent and update their keys for the newer PPA.